# How to stop animation in one layer without affecting another layer in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

**Introduction**

I have three canvases overlayed on each other. To my understanding, each canvases are independent. I have id the layers into layer1, layer2 and layer3.

```
  ctx1 = document.getElementById('layer1').getContext('2d');
  ctx2 = document.getElementById('layer2').getContext('2d');
  ctx3 = document.getElementById('layer3').getContext('2d');

  var canvasOneWidth = ctx1.canvas.width;
  var canvasOneHeight = ctx1.canvas.height;

  var canvasTwoWidth = ctx2.canvas.width;
  var canvasTwoHeight = ctx2.canvas.height;

  var canvasThreeWidth = ctx3.canvas.width;
  var canvasThreeHeight = ctx3.canvas.height;
```

The code I have written so far does the following.

I have created 10 arrows (arrow A) from the same image through for-loop and  1 arrow (arrow B) of a different image also through a for-loop. All those arrows are store in the same array. I have put (arrow A) on layer1 and (arrow B) on layer2. Both (arrow A) and (arrow B) is able animate. Both animation is done by the same animate() function in the code

**array below**

```
var arrows = []; // group of (arrow A) and one of (arrow B) are stored here
```

**forloop that creates 10 (arrow A) below**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var randx = getRandomInt(-1500, -100);
    var randy = getRandomInt(10, 300); // put a fixed position
    var rand_rate = getRandomInt(10, 50);
    var rand_vel = getRandomInt(10, 20);
    var rand_rate = getRandomInt(10, 50);

    var new_arrows = new arrow(randx, randy, canvasOneWidth, canvasOneHeight, 'images/arrow1_dup.png', rand_vel, rand_rate);
    arrows.push(new_arrows);
  }
```

**fooloop that create one (arrow B) below**

```
for (var i=0; i<1;i++) {
    var theArrow = new arrow(lastArrow.startx, lastArrow.y, canvasTwoWidth, canvasTwoHeight, 'images/arrow_500x50.png', 10, 20);
    arrows.push(theArrow);
  }
```

**(arrow A) function below**

```
var drawArrow = function (arrows, width, height) {
    var img;
    var arrLength = arrows.length;

    doAnimation = true;

      ctx1.save();
      clearCanvas(1);
      for(var i=0; i<arrLength-1; i++){
        var arrow = arrows[i];
        img = new Image();
        img.src = arrow.getFilename();
        imageWidth = img.naturalWidth;
        imageHeight = img.naturalHeight;
        ctx1.drawImage(img, arrow.getX(), arrow.getY());
        arrows[i].moveArrow(imageWidth, ctx1);
      }
      ctx1.restore();

      return 0;
  };
```

**(arrow B) function below**

```
var initLastArrow = function(callback) {

    var finalArrow = arrows[arrows.length - 1];
    var img;

    doAnimation = true;

    img = new Image();
    img.src = finalArrow.getFilename();
    imageWidth = img.naturalWidth;
    imageHeight = img.naturalHeight;

    ctx3.drawImage(img, finalArrow.getX(), finalArrow.getY());

    arrows[arrows.length - 1].moveArrow(imageWidth, ctx3);

    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback(finalArrow.getX());
    }

  };
```

**animation code below**

```
 var animate = function () {
    clearCanvas(1);
    clearCanvas(2);
    clearCanvas(3);
    var s = drawArrow(arrows, canvasOneWidth, canvasOneHeight);
      if(s == 0) {
        initLastArrow(function(finalArrowX) {
          if (finalArrowX > 80) {
            doAnimation = false;
            console.log("yay");
            drawLogo();
          }
        });
      }

      if (doAnimation) {
        requestAnimFrame(function() {
          animate();
        });
      }
    };
```

**This is what I am trying to do**

I am trying to do an animation where the group of (arrow A) and one (arrow B) move from left to right of the canvas. When (arrow B) reaches the middle of the canvas, it should stop animation. While at the same time the stopping of (arrow B) should not affect the animation of (arrow A).

**Here is the problem**

When I stop the animation of (arrow B), the animation of the group of (arrow A) stops together. I can't seem to separately stop one layer without affecting another layer and I have searched and tried many codes and still unable to solve this animation problem.

I am hoping to find help here on stackoverflow people because some of you guys have the capacity to solve this problem at ease, a skill I'm yet to have. I appreciate your help in advance.

**Full code** on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/irwinsharma05/je86xtb1/1/

PS: 1. arrow A and arrow B are images and 2. All listed defines and functions are relevant to help solve the problem.

Comment: The JSfiddle is not running.

Comment: If you stop the recursive function everything stops...  `if(doAnimation){    requestAnimFrame(animate)}`

Comment: I apologize for that. I am not sure how to add an external image to the fiddle but the code does work, just have to replace the image with a local image.

Comment: Use a single `requestAnimationFrame`. Add a boolean `isAnimating` property to each `new Arrow`. When you update the position of each arrow set each `isAnimating` to true or false indicating if that arrow should continue animating. If any arrow has `isAnimating===false` then don't update its position anymore.

Comment: @markE do you mean I should have the requestAnimFrame inside each animating functions?

Comment: No. One single requestAnimationFrame that triggers all updates and all renderings. If any particular arrow is updated in position depends on its `isAnimating` flag. Set any particular arrow's flag when it reaches its desired ending position. :-)

Comment: @markE It works man.By adding an isAnimating boolean into the property of the arrow object.

Answer (score 0):

Trying overlaying the canvas with `div` elements and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div id="layer1">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <div id="layer2">over the canvas</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#layer1 {
  position: relative;
}
#layer1 canvas, #layer2 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the canvas is being animated, in this case layer1 is canvas 1 and layer 2 is canvas 2. How will putting in a <div> without referencing the specific canvas would solve my problem?